# Virtual Hair on Detected face using Emgu CV - C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, face-detection

My current project has required me to learn face detection/tracking and image processing, given my experience in c#, I chose `Emgu CV` as my choice library for face detection and tracking. From what I've learned so far, I can do face detection and tracking, and basic image processing.

My goal is to be able to place virtual hair on the detected face. What I want to achieve is similar to [this video]: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdPmECfUFcI.

What I would like to know is the technique(s) to use in handling hair placement for different kind of hairstyles on the detected face. In what image format do I store the the hair?

Comment: What exactly is your problem ? Is it about the upscale/downscale of the "hair" figure ? Is it about deciding how to align the "hair" figure with the detected head ? Something else ?

Comment: @mmgp, yes, my problem is how to align the hair figure with the detected head, which I believe will take care of the scaling of the hair as well.

Comment: Two distinct problems, solve one at a time. Suppose you know the scale, for the moment. Do you have the minimum bounding box of the head or is it axis aligned ? If the former, what is the alignment problem ?

Comment: @mmgp, When you say "scale" and axis, do you mean the width,height and (x,y) axis of the detected face? If yes, then yes, I can get those values using emgu cv. What do you mean by "minimum bounding box of the head"? I should also point out to you that I've not tried any solution yet in terms of the hair placement on the detected face. I asked this question so I could get a guild line on how to achieve that, than trying blind solution. How do I place the hair to align properly on the detected face?

Comment: I didn't say "scale", it is a scale problem too (there are no quotes, it is not a made up term, or anything like that). Minimum bounding box is also an actual term, I don't understand what is not understood by it. I will post a guideline as an answer then, if you don't mind, without any algorithm.

Comment: Thanks mmgp, guideline is actually what am looking for, at least at this stage to give me heads-up on how to achieve this. Thanks, waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After watching the video I noticed it considers the head as a flat rectangle and not as a rectangular prism (the 3D object), so it doesn't consider the use of perspective transformations and I will not consider it too. This is a limitation but serves as a decent first step in doing such placements. Note that it is not a simply matter of taking perspective into consideration, your face tracking algorithm also needs to be able to handle more complicated configurations (the eyes might not be fully visible, for example).

So, the first thing you want is a bounding rectangle aligned according to the angle the eyes make with the x axis, illustrated in the following right figure (the red segment indicates the connection between the eyes). The left figure shows a typical bounding box aligned to the axis, which doesn't serve for this problem.

[image]

The problem is also simplified after you consider the head is symmetric, so you know the top middle point in the above figure is the middle of the top of your head. Also, considering that a typical head will likely be larger at top than at bottom, then you have something like in the following figure where the width of the rectangle is close to the width of the forehead. You could also consider a bounding rectangle on only upper half of the head, for example.

[image]

Now all that is left is positioning some object in this rectangle. For that, you need to augment the description of this object to be positioned so it is not purely pixels. We can define "entrance width" (EW) and "entrance middle point" (EM). This EW establishes the width needed  in the other rectangle (the head one) to position it. So, if EW is smaller than the needed value, you upscale this object, respectively for when EW is larger. Note that the full width of the head's rectangle is usually an overestimation to position this object, so you can experiment with percentages of the width. The EM value is useful to know how you will position this object over the head. In the following figure, EW is the horizontal blue dashed horizontal, and EM is the middle point on it. The vertical blue line indicates how much over the EM you want to move this object inside the top segment of head's rectangle.

[image]

The only other special thing this object needs is a value that is considered as background. So when painting this object it is easy to know whether to make a point fully transparent (the background value) or fully opaque (anything else). This was the sketch I had in mind of what needs to be basically done.

Comment: Thank you for this guideline, now I have a better understanding on how to go about this. But one thing I still don't understand yet is the EW. Assuming the last figure is in png format with transparent background, how do you handle the upscale/downscale starting just from the edge of the EW, and making sure the other (right) end stops at the expected (right) end of the head's rectangle? Hope you understand my question?

Comment: In the simplest way (like in the video), you upscale/downscale the whole figure. Suppose EW = 400 pixels in the original png figure (I would rather have a big initial figure and always only downscale it rather than upscale because this will likely introduce artifacts). Also suppose you want to fit it in something of width 300 pixels. Since you have to reduce the radius by 50 pixels, the wig's width is reduced by 100 and the height is reduced accordingly to keep the aspect ratio. Now I think your other question is why EW fits the head. That is simple: EW fits the head because you calculated it.

Comment: Maybe I understood your doubt now. Let's suppose this object has width W in total, and w is the EW. If we need to change w by some scale k, we resize the entire image. So, for example, if w = 10 pixels and we want to reduce it by half, we have to reduce W by half (and not only by 5 pixels, in this case, as was pointed out in the comment above). Is this the actual doubt ?

Comment: That's exactly my doubt. Thanks to your answer and comments, I've been able to see more possible solution from your posts. The approach in your last comment, I think, is how I intend to do the hair placement. The hair will be created in such a way that the face will be required to be at the middle (from the EW perspective) of the hair to fit on both edges, that way, I will just up or down scale the hair based on the face's rect and recalculate the hair alignment based on the face position. Thanks very much.